# R shiny- Could not find a function min_var and max_sr (renderHighchart)

Tags: r, plotly, markdown, shiny-server, shinyapps

Could you please help find an issue in my R-shiny code?
I pasted the whole R-markdown script and it works for the second tab "output" however for the first-named as "Portfel efektywny" there is an issue with a function that cannot be found however it has been implemented properly ...
**Warning: Error in min_var: could not find function "min_var"**
**Warning: Error in max_sr: could not find function "max_sr"**

I will be very grateful for your kind help :)
Thx in advance !!!

```
---
title: "Monte_Carlo_Projekt"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    
---
```

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyquant)
library(plotly)
library(timetk)
library(scales)
```

## Sidebar {.sidebar}

```
fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("stock1", "Stock 1", "SPY")),
  column(5,
  numericInput("w1", "Portf. %", 25, min = 1, max = 100))
)  

fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("stock2", "Stock 2", "EFA")),
  column(5,
  numericInput("w2", "Portf. %", 25, min = 1, max = 100))
)

fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("stock3", "Stock 3", "IJS")),
  column(5,
  numericInput("w3", "Portf. %", 20, min = 1, max = 100))
)

fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("stock4", "Stock 4", "EEM")),
  column(5,
  numericInput("w4", "Portf. %", 20, min = 1, max = 100))
)

fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("stock5", "Stock 5", "AGG")),
  column(5,
  numericInput("w5", "Portf. %", 10, min = 1, max = 100))
)

fluidRow(
  column(7,
  dateInput("date", "Starting Date", "2013-01-01", format = "yyyy-mm-dd"))
)

fluidRow(
  column(5,
  numericInput("sim_months", "Months", 120, min = 6, max = 240, step = 6)),
  column(5,
  numericInput("sims", "Sims", 51, min = 31, max = 101, step = 10)),
  column(5,
  numericInput("mar", "MAR%", .8, min = 0, max = 3, step = .01)),
  column(5,
  numericInput("window", "Window", 6, min = 2, max = 24, step = 2))
)

actionButton("go", "Submit")
```

```
#Tu dodajemy wszystkie funkcje
prices <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  
  symbols <- c(input$stock1, input$stock2, input$stock3, input$stock4, input$stock5)
  getSymbols(symbols, src = 'yahoo', from = input$date, 
             auto.assign = TRUE, warnings = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>% 
  reduce(merge) %>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)
})

mar <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$mar/100})

rolling_sortino <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  validate(need(input$w1 + input$w2 + input$w3 + input$w4 + input$w5 == 100, "The portfolio weights must sum to 100%!"))
  
  prices <- prices()
  w <- c(input$w1/100, input$w2/100, input$w3/100, input$w4/100, input$w5/100)
  MAR <- mar()
  window <- input$window

prices_monthly <- to.monthly(prices, indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE)
asset_returns_xts <- na.omit(Return.calculate(prices_monthly, method = "log"))

cov_mat <- cov(asset_returns_xts) * 12

mean_ret <- colMeans(asset_returns_xts)

portfolio_returns_xts_rebalanced_monthly <- Return.portfolio(asset_returns_xts, weights = w, rebalance_on = "months")

rolling_sortino <-
  apply.rolling(portfolio_returns_xts_rebalanced_monthly, window, 
            fun = 'SortinoRatio',  MAR = MAR) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(paste(window, "-month rolling sortino", sep=""))
})
help("apply.rolling")

portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- eventReactive(input$go, {
validate(need(input$w1 + input$w2 + input$w3 + input$w4 + input$w5 == 100, "The portfolio weights must sum to 100%!"))
  prices <- prices()
  w <- c(input$w1/100, input$w2/100, input$w3/100, input$w4/100, input$w5/100)
  
  asset_returns_long <- 
      prices %>% 
      to.monthly(indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE) %>% 
      tk_tbl(preserve_index = TRUE, rename_index = "date") %>%
      gather(asset, returns, -date) %>% 
      group_by(asset) %>%  
      mutate(returns = (log(returns) - log(lag(returns))))
  
  sims <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$sims})
  
  sims <- sims()

# Creating a matrix to store the weights
all_wts <- matrix(nrow = sims, ncol = length(symbols))

# Creating an empty vector to store Portfolio returns, Portfolio Standard deviation, Portfolio Sharpe Ratio
port_returns <- vector('numeric', length = sims)
port_risk <- vector('numeric', length = sims)
sharpe_ratio <- vector('numeric', length = sims)

for (i in seq_along(port_returns)) {
  
  wts <- runif(length(symbols))
  wts <- wts/sum(wts)

  all_wts[i,] <- wts # Storing weight in the matrix
  
  port_ret <- sum(wts * mean_ret) # Portfolio returns
  port_ret <- ((port_ret + 1)^12) - 1
  
  port_returns[i] <- port_ret # Storing Portfolio Returns values
  
  port_sd <- sqrt(t(wts) %*% (cov_mat  %*% wts)) # Creating and storing portfolio risk
  port_risk[i] <- port_sd
  
  sr <- port_ret/port_sd # Creating and storing Portfolio Sharpe Ratios, 
  sharpe_ratio[i] <- sr #Assuming 0% Risk free rate
  
}

# Storing the values in the table
portfolio_values <- tibble(Return = port_returns,
                           Risk = port_risk,
                           SharpeRatio = sharpe_ratio)

# Converting matrix to a tibble and changing column names
all_wts <- tk_tbl(all_wts)

colnames(all_wts) <- colnames(asset_returns_xts)

# Combing all the values together
portfolio_values <- tk_tbl(cbind(all_wts, portfolio_values))

# calculating the minimum variance portfolio

min_var <- eventReactive(input$go, { 
portfolio_values[which.min(portfolio_values$Risk),]
  
})

# calculating the tangency portfolio (the portfolio with highest sharpe ratio)
max_sr <- eventReactive(input$go, { 
  portfolio_values[which.max(portfolio_values$SharpeRatio),]

})

MAR <- mar()

portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- 
  asset_returns_long %>% 
  tq_portfolio(assets_col = asset, 
               returns_col = returns, 
               weights = w,
               col_rename = "returns",
               rebalance_on = "months") %>% 
  mutate(returns_below_MAR = ifelse(returns < MAR, returns, NA)) %>%
  mutate(returns_above_MAR = ifelse(returns > MAR, returns, NA))

portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly
})


portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  
  prices <- prices()
  w <- c(input$w1/100, input$w2/100, input$w3/100, input$w4/100, input$w5/100)
  
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- 
      prices %>% 
      to.monthly(indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE) %>% 
      tk_tbl(preserve_index = TRUE, rename_index = "date") %>%
      gather(asset, returns, -date) %>% 
      group_by(asset) %>%  
      mutate(returns = (log(returns) - log(lag(returns)))) %>%
  tq_portfolio(assets_col  = asset, 
               returns_col = returns,
               weights     = w,
               col_rename  = "returns",
               rebalance_on = "months")
})

mean_port_return <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly()
  
  mean(portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly$returns)
})

stddev_port_return <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly()
  
  sd(portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly$returns)
})

simulation_accum_1 <- function(init_value, N, mean, stdev) {
    tibble(c(init_value, 1 + rnorm(N, mean, stdev))) %>% 
    `colnames<-`("returns") %>%
    mutate(growth = accumulate(returns, function(x, y) x * y)) %>% 
    select(growth)
}

sims <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$sims})

monte_carlo_sim_51 <- eventReactive(input$go, { 
  
  sims <- sims()
  
  starts <-  
    rep(1, sims) %>%
    set_names(paste("sim", 1:sims, sep = ""))
  
  map_dfc(starts, simulation_accum_1,
          N = input$sim_months, mean = mean_port_return(), 
          stdev = stddev_port_return()) %>% 
  mutate(month = seq(1:nrow(.))) %>% 
  select(month, everything()) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("month", names(starts))) %>% 
  gather(sim, growth, -month) %>% 
  group_by(sim) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(round(., 2)))
  
})
```

## Portfel efektywny

### Row {data-height=600, .tabset}

#### Minimum Variance Portfolio Weights

```
renderPlotly({
  validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, weights, MAR, rolling window and start date and click submit."))
  
  
  min_var <- min_var()
  
  min_var %>%
  gather(AAPL:TSLA, key = Asset,
         value = Weights) %>%
  mutate(Asset = as.factor(Asset)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(Asset,Weights), y = Weights, fill = Asset)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = 'Assets', y = 'Weights', title = "Minimum Variance Portfolio Weights") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)  
})
```

#### Tangency Portfolio Weights

```
renderHighchart({
  hchart( max_sr(), 
       type = 'bar', 
       hcaes(y = Weights,
             x = fct_reorder(Asset,Weights),
             group = Asset)) %>% 
  hc_title(text = paste(sims(), "Tangency Portfolio Weights", sep = " ")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Assets")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Weights"),
           labels = list(format = "${value}")) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat()) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
})
```

### Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}

#### portfolio optimization & efficient frontier

```
renderHighchart({
validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, months, number of simulations and start date and click submit."))
  
  
})
```

## output

### Row {data-height=600, .tabset}

#### Symulacje

```
renderHighchart(
  hchart( monte_carlo_sim_51(), 
       type = 'line', 
       hcaes(y = growth,
             x = month,
             group = sim)) %>% 
  hc_title(text = paste(sims(), "Simulations", sep = " ")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "months")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "dollar growth"),
           labels = list(format = "${value}")) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat()) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
)
```

#### Min, Max, Median Sim

```
renderHighchart({
validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, months, number of simulations and start date and click submit."))
 
sim_summary <- 
  monte_carlo_sim_51() %>%
  summarise(final = last(growth)) %>% 
  summarise(
            max = max(final), 
            min = min(final),
            median = median(final))

mc_max_med_min <- 
  monte_carlo_sim_51() %>%
  filter(
      last(growth) == sim_summary$max || 
      last(growth) == sim_summary$median ||
      last(growth) == sim_summary$min)

  hchart(mc_max_med_min, 
       type = 'line', 
       hcaes(y = growth,
             x = month,
             group = sim)) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Min Max Median Simulations") %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "months")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "dollar growth"),
           labels = list(format = "${value}")) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat()) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
})
```

### Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}

#### Histogram

```
renderPlot({
  validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, weights, MAR, rolling window and start date and click submit."))
  MAR <- mar()
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly()
  
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = returns)) +
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.25, binwidth = .01, fill = "cornflowerblue") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = MAR, color = "green") +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = MAR, 
             y = 10, label = "MAR", fontface = "plain", 
             angle = 90, alpha = .5, vjust =  1)
})
```

#### Density

```
renderPlot({
  validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, weights, MAR, rolling window and start date and click submit."))
  MAR <- mar()
  portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly <- portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly()
  
  sortino_density_plot <- portfolio_returns_tq_rebalanced_monthly %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = returns)) +
    stat_density(geom = "line", size = 1, color = "cornflowerblue") 
  
  shaded_area_data <- ggplot_build(sortino_density_plot)$data[[1]] %>% 
    filter(x < MAR)

  sortino_density_plot + 
  geom_area(data = shaded_area_data, aes(x = x, y = y), fill="pink", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_segment(data = shaded_area_data, aes(x = MAR, y = 0, xend = MAR, yend = y), 
               color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = MAR, y = 5, label = paste("MAR =", MAR, sep = ""), 
           fontface = "plain", angle = 90, alpha = .8, vjust =  -1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = (MAR - .02), y = .1, label = "Downside", 
           fontface = "plain", alpha = .8, vjust =  -1)
           
})
```

#### Rolling Sortino

```
renderHighchart({
  
validate(need(input$go != 0, "Please choose your portfolio assets, weights, MAR, rolling window and start date and click submit."))
  
  
  highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_title(text = names(rolling_sortino())) %>%
  hc_add_series(rolling_sortino(), name = names(rolling_sortino()), color = "cornflowerblue") %>%
  hc_navigator(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_scrollbar(enabled = FALSE) 
 
})
```

Comment: We don't want your *whole* script.  We need a *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `min_var( )` and `max_sr( )`, i.e. you are calling them as functions. They are not functions. The way that it works is that whenever an event occurs (in this case `input$go`), stuff happens, which will be stored in `min_var` and `max_sr`.